# Get rich text formatting gem working with rails admin on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline, rich-text-editor

For my project I'm using rails_admin and try to use rich text formatting gem. Locally everything works fine, but it won't work in production on heroku. I get the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (rich/editor.css isn't precompiled)
```

This is how I precompile:

```
config.assets.precompile << *.js
```

And I also tried this:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
```

UPDATE:

I'm precompiling the assets locally before deploying to heroku by running this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and i have this in my application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require rich/editor
*= require_tree .
```

Anyone who can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with the assets pipeline.

> There are two ways you can use the asset pipeline on Heroku.
>
> 1. Compiling assets locally.
> 2. Compiling assets during slug compilation.

There's full documentation here on both methods.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

UPDATE:

Have you tried adding?

```
config.assets.precompile << 'rich/editor.css'
```

to your application.rb?

BTW,incase you didn't know: To save you pushing to Heroku to test every time you should check to see if the contents of editor.css is in the generated public/assets/application.css file.

Comment: I updated my Question: I'm precompiling locally without errors and anything else is precompiled and working, just not this rich/editor.css